# Why would a system tray icon clear an earlier-displayed one?

Tags: c++, windows, system-tray

We have an application that uses various system tray icons to communicate with users. Different icons indicate different internal states of the (otherwise windowless) application. We implemented our system tray stuff using code from [this Code Guru project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/systemtray.aspx) (the MFC version; this is not a new application by any means), and until recently, it has worked fine. However, recently we have tried to add another icon and have run into trouble.

Here's how it's *supposed* to work:

1. We have one main icon (call it 'A') that indicates that the application is running.
2. If a particular event occurs, we display icon 'B', over which the user can hover their mouse to get a tooltip with status regarding that event.
3. If a (recently added, internal, threaded) procedure starts, we display icon 'C', and again, the user can hover over that to see a tooltip that indicates the progress of that activity.

What's *actually* happening: if icon 'B' is visible when we (try to) display icon 'C', then icon 'B' either disappears entirely, never to return, or it stays there and icon 'C' never shows up, but the tooltip for icon 'B' is changed to what icon 'C' should have.

I've simplified the scenario a bit; we actually have a few other icons, but they're rarely used. However, we have never had any trouble displaying multiple icons until we added icon 'C' in the last couple of weeks.

Any ideas? Happy to clarify anything I haven't explained well.

Comment: Show us your calls to Shell_NotifyIcon.

Comment: Well, OK. But what's in `m_tnd`? It sounds like you are reusing the `NOTIFYICONDATA` structs or perhaps passing the same `hWnd` and `UID` for all icons.

Comment: For showing:
 Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &m_tnd)
For hiding:
  Shell_NotifyIcon (NIM_DELETE, &m_tnd);

(m_tnd, a NOTIFYICONDATA structure, is a member of the CSystemTray class (written by the person who posted the CodeGuru project I referenced). It is populated when the class is initialized.

Comment: Each icon has its own CSystemTray class and therefore its own NOTIFYICONDATA dedicated to it.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that, for these two icons particularly, we often send multiple 'show' commands without hiding them in between.

However, the CSystemTray 'ShowIcon' and 'HideIcon' methods keep track of whether the icons are in view, and only send the Shell_NotifyIcon() calls if they are warranted.

Comment: And each icon has a different hWnd/uID pair? This is important because otherwise the shell thinks there only is one icon.

Comment: Hm, we aren't setting the uID. They're all zero. That's probably the problem! Want to put that in an Answer? I'll test it out.

Is there anything special about the uID or is it just our own internal value for the icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a different `uID` for each icon. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) says:

> The application-defined identifier of the taskbar icon. The Shell uses either (hWnd plus uID) or guidItem to identify which icon to operate on when Shell_NotifyIcon is invoked. You can have multiple icons associated with a single hWnd by assigning each a different uID. If guidItem is specified, uID is ignored.

In other words you need to pick a value for `uID`. This is how the shell knows which icon you are referring to each time you call `Shell_NotifyIcon()`. Clearly you must use a different value for each icon. So, use `0` for icon `A`, `1` for icon `B` etc.

Comment: It turns out we were using different IDs for all the icons ... except those two. Never even noticed (and missed that vital part of the documentation). Thanks!